# I C# treeView shows folder sequence nodes How to rename nodes Recurrently on form load without changing source folder name

Tags: c#, treeview

I have form showing treeview that treeview preview some folders, subfolders and files from the hard drive like the following example :

[image: TreeView]

how to change the names of the nodes in the treeview without changing the source folder name

I mean that I need to change the node name just in the form 
for example, a node named "debug" show to the user like "XXX" but the folder still named debug

Comment: Find the node you want to change, and then do `node.Text = "XXX"`.

Comment: at first i to thank you for your fast response @Neil but i am an beginner can you tell me how to find an specific node programmatecly

Comment: I usually create my own custom TreeNode (MyTreeNode) class which inheirts the standard TreeNode.  Then add a property for Pathname so the Node has both the Display Name and the Path Name.

Comment: @jdweng ok if i want to preview c:/ partion folders and files in at treeview with changing some folder names in treeview only without change the folder name in c:/ can you share with me code example

Comment: Did you create a MyTreeNode?  Store Pathname as property Name.  Next put for Custom Property Display Name what you want to display in GUI.  then change you code to disply GUI to use Display Name instead of Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First of all, I can't tell if you are using Windows Forms or WPF, so I'm going to explain it for Windows Forms.

---

Make a `ContextMenuStrip`, then make a `DropdownItem` with the text being `Rename`

**Next**, double-click the item; this will open the `Form.cs` of the `Form` containing the `TreeView`

**Now**, make a new form, by clicking the `Project` button, which is located in the top-bar of **Visual Studio**, (Which I assume you are using) and click `Add Windows Form` - This will open a window asking what name the `Form` should be.

**Next**, after adding the new form, create a `TextBox` on the new `Form`, and a `Button`, with the text being `Rename`

**Okay**, now that we've covered that part, go back to the `Form.cs` and navigate to the `rename_Click()` event. (I'm sure that the event name isn't actually `rename_Click()`, it's just an example)

**Now**, put this code in between the curly brackets(Code Block):

```
renameForm rf = new renameForm();
rf.ShowDialog();
```

**OKAY!** Now, we need to head back to the other `Form` we created earlier. Open the `Form.cs` of the earlier created `Form`, and scroll to the top. Before the `public Form()` event, type:

```
public static string newName = "";
```

**So!** When the parent `Form` that contains our `ContextMenuStrip` and `TreeView` opens our second `Form`

**But**, now, we will need to send data back, right?

Go back to the `rename_Click()` in the parent `Form`, the one that contains our `TreeView` and `ContextMenuStrip`, and before the `rf.ShowDialog();`, add:

```
rf.FormClosed += rename_Closed;
```

***you may need to press TAB to create the event if it does not already exist***

In the second `Form`, containing our `TextBox` and `Button`, double-click the `Button`, and open the `Form.cs`

Inside of the curly brackets(Code Block) of the `button_Click()`, add:

```
 newName = textBox1.Text;
```

Then, inside of the curly brackets(Code Block) of `rename_Closed()`, add:

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Text = renameForm.newName;
```

---

### This should create a *simple*, but effective rename system.

---

Hope it helps you :)